# Working with consecutive events in drools

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

I need help with the following rule:

Accounts with multiple consecutive deposits and immediately after 4 hours, multiple extractions whose sum is equal to the same amount deposited using different ATM in the same bank. 
(There aren't intermediate operations between the last deposit and the first extraction)

I have the class Operation: Account, Amount, Operation, ATM, Timestamp.

I have this rule:

```
declare Operation 
 @role(event) 
 @timestamp(Timestamp) 
end 

rule 
when 
 $op1:Operation($acc:Account,$b:Bank,$amount:Amount,Operation‌​=="CREDIT",$atm:ATM) 
 not Operation(Account == $acc,ATM != $atm, Bank == $b, this before $op1) accumulate($op2:Operation(Account == $acc,ATM != $atm, Bank == $b,Operation=="CREDIT",$amount1:Amount);$c:count($op2),$d:su‌​m($amount1);$c>=4,$d‌​>=300) 
then 
 System.out.println( "Account: " + $acc + " amount " + ($amount + $d) + " operations " + $c+ " in different banks"); 
end
```

The previous rule returns the sum of the deposits of the accounts that have made more than 4 operations in different ATMs of the same bank,my doubt is how to take into account that they are consecutive and that after 4 hours compare the previous sum with the sum of the extractions from that account.

Comment: What did you try so far? - Or: where do I find your tender?

Comment: Don't post code in comments, that's hardly readable. - You can edit your question.

Comment: I think that this must be handled by setting up a monitor for a certain account as soon as there are n deposits without an extraction. Then, additional events will be handled considering the state of the monitor. Let's seet the rule edited into the question.

Comment: I edited the question with the rule. I do not understand when you say "this must be handled by setting up a monitor for a certain account ....". Please,would you explain me with more details?

Answer (score 0):

If this rule fires,

```
rule "set up Monitor"
when
  $op1: Operation( $a:account, $b:bank, $amt1:amount, operation‌​=="CREDIT", $atm1: atm )
  $op2: Operation( account==$a, bank==$b, $amt2:amount, operation‌​=="CREDIT", atm!= $atm1 )
  not Operation(account == $acc, atm != $atm1, bank == $b,
                this before $op2, this after $op1 )
  not Monitor( bank == $bank, account == $acc )
then
  insert( new Monitor( $bank, $acc, $amt1 + $amt2, "CREDIT" );
end
```

you have a Monitor inserted. The monitor has the obvious fields and a state field, set to "CREDIT".

```
rule "add deposit"
when
  $op1: Operation( $a:account, $b:bank, $amt1:amount, operation‌​=="CREDIT", $atm1: atm )
  $mon: Monitor( account==$a, bank==$b, $bal: balance, state == "CREDIT" )
then
  // another deposit
  modify( $op1 ){ setAmount( $bal + $amt1 ) }
end
```

With this event, the state changes to withdrawal.

```
rule "state changes to withdrawal"
when
  $op1: Operation( $a:account, $b:bank, $amt1: amount, operation‌​=="WITHDRAW", $atm1: atm )
  $mon: Monitor( account==$a, bank==$b, $bal: balance, state == "CREDIT" )
then
  // switch to withdraw
  modify( $op1 ){ setAmount( $bal + $amt1 ),
                  setState( "WITHDRAW" ) }
end
```

And here it begins to get messy. We need to check whether this (first) withdrawal cashes in on all deposits (`balance == $amt1`) or just reduces the balance or withdraws more than the previous sequence of deposits have made.

I quit here, but I think I've shown that this isn't possible to do with a single rule.